# Yii: Update HTML after ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm trying to show data based on input text.

I've created ajax-enabled input:

```
echo CHtml::textField("input_tracking",'',array('id'=>'input_tracking','ajax' => array(
'type' =>'POST',
'url' => CController::createUrl('report/getTracking'),
'update' => '#tracking_result',
'data' => 'html'
)));
```

But it sending empty $_POST. What I'm doing wrong?

My controller code:

```
    $data=MyModel::model()->findAll('tracking=:input_tracking',
        array(':input_tracking'=>(int) $_POST['input_tracking']));

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
            array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ajax call is quite wrong. You dont pass any data to controller, thats why POST is empty. Should be like this:

```
          'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('report/getTracking'),   
            'update' => '#tracking_result',                        
            'data'=>array('input_tracking'=>'js:this.value',),  
//If this wont work replace update with success function        
    'success'=> 'function(data) {                                             
        $("#tracking_result").empty();
        $("#tracking_result").append(data);

            } ',

        )));
```

Your controller is fine. Hope this was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try it without the 'data' array index and tell us what happens?

You can take a look at this wiki to accomplish something like what you are trying to do.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/